# Communicating different properties in multiple faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf

Is there a way by which different managed beans in different faces-config.xml placed in multiple WARs.

Comment: try to read your question and if something doesn't feel right, update it. ;)

Comment: You have X bean in A.war and you want it to communicate in Y bean in B.war?? Not sure what the question is.

Comment: Can a managed bean name "Apple" in Apple.war be consumed in "Banana" bean in Banana.war

Answer (score 0):

No, they reside in different contexts.

Depending on the servlet container, there are ways to share / synchronize the two contexts.

Using [`ServletContext.getContext(path)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.String%29) would return the other context. There you can obtain all application-scoped beans. (The context must be configured to be accessible from other contexts).

But this is too much hassle for something that should be achieved in other ways.

If you want your two applications to communicate with each other, make them a channel - via web services, JMS, etc.

**Update:** Tomcat's [Signle-Sign-On Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Single%20Sign%20On%20Valve) might be helpful (if using tomcat)

> The Single Sign On Vale is utilized when you wish to give users the ability to sign on to any one of the web applications associated with your virtual host, and then have their identity recognized by all other web applications on the same virtual host.

Comment: Let me explain you the scenario. We are in the process of developing a common framework. Lets say I have a common war which takes user input and password and on submit I forward it to different applications which are in different wars.